# Programmatically handle Cocoa events?

Tags: c++, cocoa, objective-c++

I am attempting to hook up cocoa events to a *minimal* objective-c++ cocoa message proxy that will call my c++ functions to handle the event.

For a button, OnClick, its simple, I go:

```
@interface cocoa_proxy : NSObject
    - (void)action:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation cocoa_proxy
    - (void)action:(id)sender
    {
        exit(0);
    }
@end

cocoa_proxy* proxy = [[cocoa_proxy alloc] init];
[button setTarget:proxy];
[button setAction:@selector(action:)];
```

**However I am unsure about how I could capture other events for the button (such as OnPress, OnRelease, OnEnter, OnExit, etc...) nor can I seem to capture events for a Window or View.**
Any attempt trying a similar route, with slightly differently formatted methods (from various, not quite the same, but similar questions on the web) results in an error like:

```
reason: '-[NSWindow setTarget:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance xxxxx
```

I already have a large codebase that I want to reuse, so it is paramount that I have a proxy, rather than just "do everything in objective-c++".

For completeness, here is how I create the Window

```
window = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(x, y, w, h)
    styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO]
        autorelease];
```

To be clear, I do not use XCode, or Interface Builder, or any GUI creation software or Cocoa aware software, or utilize concepts such as NIBs, everything is done procedurally and with minimal interaction with objective-c++.

So my question is, how do I handle different events for a Button, and how do I handle events (at all), in a similar manner for Windows and Views.

Answer (score 0):

The action method fired by a button when it is clicked (complete press and release sequence), is not an event as such. It's the consequence of a series of events.

It's not entirely clear at what level you need to operate, but you may need to use a custom subclass of `NSApplication` and override `-sendEvent:`. There you will get the low-level events like left-mouse-button-down, left-mouse-button-up, key-down, key-up, etc.

If you are only interested in a single window, you could instead use a custom subclass of `NSWindow` and override `-sendEvent:` there.

If you don't allow events to be processed through Cocoa in the normal way (by calling through to `super` in either override), then you are responsible for all application responses to events. You can rely on clicks in the window controls to close, minimize, or full-screen/zoom the window. Clicks on Cocoa buttons won't work. Etc. So, you have to choose carefully what you do or don't do with the events.

To just get additional control over a button, you would subclass `NSButton`, `NSButtonCell`, or both and override a bunch of methods. For example, you would probable want to override `-startTrackingAt:inView:`, `-continueTracking:at:inView:`, and `-stopTracking:at:inView:mouseIsUp:` in your button cell class.

Comment: I want Cocoa to handle the events as it normally would, but I would also like to respond to those events.  For example, when the window resizes, I have additional calculations I need to perform.  I want to do this in a generic enough way that if I decide I also want MouseMove events, I don't have to write a completely new interface to respond to those as well, if you follow me.

Comment: Those are implemented as very different sorts of things in Cocoa. A window emits a notification (`NSWindowDidResizeNotification`) when it resizes, which is different from a button click (action method), which is different from a low-level event (mouse-move). In case it helps, I'm *very* familiar with this sort of thing because I wrote [code to translate from Cocoa stuff to Win32](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/winemac.drv/) (warning: LGPLv2-licensed code).

Comment: I am used to either the Event message system of something like GTK or the message pump style in Win32, but if I subclass NSWindow, and NSView, and NSButton, etc..., I should be able to overload their event messages, call their supers, and "handle them" as I normally would, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: As I say, certain things (window resizing) will require observing notifications or setting an object of yours as a delegate. However, let me back up: I find it difficult to imagine what sort of common code you might have that could be useful for such low-level details as, as you put it, OnPress, OnRelease, OnEnter, OnExit. What could such code do that wouldn't collide with what Cocoa is already doing (highlighting the button, etc.)? I think it will be much more fruitful to use common code for "business logic" rather than event handling and UI manipulation.

Comment: There is no code in the code base that is not event handling and UI manipulation, and this is abstracted out to hide the implementation details so that the underpinnings can be written on any GUI toolkit.  Subclassing major components to deal with their messages is not ideal, but if it must be done, it must be done.